# Convert HTML5 Charts to PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, charts

I am making a tool that needs to generate a PDF report with charts and tables from data that was imported via excel upload.

I would like use HTML5 charts.  We are currently using PHP.

I am looking for a a real browser (or something that behaves like a browser) in order to have those html5 charts rendered properly.  The new html5 charts rely on javascript, so it's not just a matter of rendering html into pdf, but also executing javascript to generate the charts on the fly.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/export/) exports to PDF from canvas, SVG, and VML.

I'm on the team, so if you have any questions about implementation or other features, just reach out!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to convert the HTML to a CANVAS image (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), and then save via jsPDF (https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

What have *you* tried?

Comment: Currently we are using this, http://jpgraph.net/  But design wise, its not pretty. So this was the issue that came up with HTML5 charts

Comment: still requires a web browser...

Browser Compatibility

jsPDF will work in IE6+*, Firefox 3+, Chrome, Safari 3+, Opera. For IE9 and below, we lazily load a Flash shim called Downloadify which enables the files to be downloaded. (Current build does not have IE6-9 shim enabled)